# Spark Scala Vector Map ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Trying to make use of the Statistics tool in Spark for Scala and having difficulty preparing a vector that will take.

```
val featuresrdd =   features.rdd.map{_.getAs[Vector]("features")}

featuresrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MapPartitionsRDD[952] at map at <console>:82
```

This produces a vector of type 'mllib.linalg.vector', however upon using this in the tool, the vector has changed to type 'DenseVector'.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(featuresrdd, "pearson")

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As I noted in your previous question, you should explore how to do what you need to do with `DataFrame`s (in the `spark.ml` package) rather than `RDD`s. The `RDD`-based API is all but deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `asML` function to convert old Vector to new Vector in ML:

```
val newMLFeaturesRDD = featuresrdd.map(_.asML)
val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(newMLFeaturesRDD , "pearson")
```

Comment: As an aside, the OP could use some idiomatic Scala when he feels comfortable: `featuresrdd.map(_.asML)`

Comment: @Vidya Sure, I changed it. That is a result when Java programmer writes answer while being at break at work :)